# How to check if string exists in array in a Jenkins Declarative pipeline step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I need to check if string exists in an array of strings, in a Jenkins Declarative pipeline step.
I cannot find any documentation on operators, except some groovy docs, which suggest using `!in`, but that does not work, so not sure if those apply here. This is what I tried and it is not working, `!in` is not regocnized:

```
def approvalResult
pipeline {

....

  stage('Setup') {
    steps {
      script {
        approvalResult = input message: 'Approve prod deployment',
          submitter: 'john@example.com',
          submitterparameter: ''
        
        echo "Build was approved by ${approvalResult}"
        //approvalResult contains string with the user email who clicked approve
  
        if(${approvalResult} !in ['john@example.com','admin@example.com']){
          error("This user is not approved to deploy to PROD.")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A functionally equivalent alternative for you is the `contains` method belonging to the `list` type. This will definitely work in Jenkins Pipeline Groovy:

```
if (!(['john@example.com','admin@example.com'].contains(approvalResult))) {
  error('This user is not approved to deploy to PROD.')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`!in` was added only in [Groovy 3](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html). Depending on how your Jenkins server and job is configured, your runtime groovy version might be <3. You can find out by:

```
println GroovySystem.version
```

Try the generic `!` operator:

```
if(!(${approvalResult} in ['john@example.com','admin@example.com'])){
```

Comment: `if ( ! ( "${approvalResult}" in ['john@example.com','admin@example.com']) ) {`